# Why is my SmartEnemy not following the player in my Java game and instead going to the top of the screen?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I am following the tutorial series "Java Programming: Let's Build a Game" by RealTutsGML on YouTube. I've made this class called SmartEnemy whose object is supposed to follow the player. However, when I run the game and the SmartEnemy comes on, most of the time it moves to the top of the screen and just stays there. I've tried googling the answer and using the suggestions in the comments of the video, but nothing has worked. Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong? Here is the code in SmartEnemy that makes it follow the player.

```
public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;

        float diffX = x - player.getX() - 16; 
        float diffY = x - player.getY() - 16;

        float distance = (float) Math.hypot((double)(x - player.getX()), (double)(y - player.getY()));

        velX = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffX); 
        velY = (float) ((-1.0/distance) * diffY);

        if(y <= 0 || y >= Game.HEIGHT - 32) velY *= -1; 
        if(x <= 0 || x >= Game.WIDTH - 16) velX *= -1;

        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.green, 16, 16, 0.02F, handler));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Should this be `y` not `x`?

```
        float diffY = y - player.getY() - 16;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works now. Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.